# $\cosh^{-1}({\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{2}}})=\log\Bigg({\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{(\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{2}})^2-1}}\Bigg)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, hypergeometric-function

As continuation of [Find the error in my work in $\int \sqrt{x^2-6x+7}\, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4141625/879543) I would like to understand if it is true that
$$\cosh^{-1}({\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{2}}})=\log\Bigg({\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{(\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{2}})^2-1}}\Bigg)$$
This should allow me to state that the integral of my previuos question is correctly computed by me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is true.${}$

Comment: It's just straightforward algebra. Let $X=\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{2}}$, then
$$ \begin{align} \require{cancel}
\cosh^{-1}(X) &= \log \left( X+\sqrt{X^2-1} \right) \\
X &= \cosh\left( \log \left( X+\sqrt{X^2-1} \right) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( X+\sqrt{X^2-1} + \frac{1}{X+\sqrt{X^2-1}} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\left(X+\sqrt{X^2-1}\right)^2+1}{X+\sqrt{X^2-1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{X^2+2X\sqrt{X^2-1}+X^2\cancel{-1}\cancel{+1}}{X+\sqrt{X^2-1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2X\left(\cancel{X+\sqrt{X^2-1}}\right)}{\cancel{X+\sqrt{X^2-1}}} \\
&= X
\end{align} $$

Comment: The first step should be to substitute $y=(x-3)/\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Thanks to all of you